# How do I use precision screwdrivers?

Tags: tools, screws, technique

I am talking about those small and narrow screwdrivers with a thin handle. I can't get a tight enough grip on the handle to generate enough torque to remove a small screw. Do I have to use something else with it?

Comment: This question belongs on SuperUser,with a title like "how do I remove the screws on a MacBook Pro?

Comment: No the question is still valid. How do you apply torque on needle like scewdriver?

Comment: Really Baz?  Nothing better to do?

Comment: Yea those screw drivers are used for clocks, watches and jewellery where very little torque is required! Those are tinkering screw drivers-- and as you have witnessed not designed for the job you want them for. Get those @Niall Suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are precision screwdrivers available that have larger handles, such as [this one from Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-100074336/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053):

[image: Home depot precision screwdriver set]
<sub>(source: [homedepot.com](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/300/23/2342e650-86b6-401f-95e2-bb04a35b242f_300.jpg))</sub>

In general, you press down on the tip while you screw in or out: this helps to hold the screwdriver in the slots in the screw head and allows you to use more force to turn the screw.

Comment: I happened to buy the exact same one (without knowing about the answer). They did a great job. You need philip head #00. #000 wont do it.

Comment: I'd recommend against -interchangeable- precision screwdrivers with plastic parts, especially if you need extra torque. I've had sets like this break on me. I prefer the all metal sets now.

Comment: I have a set I really like.  The handle has a hole in it near the top.  You can fit an included extension bit in that hole to make a T-shaped handle that's great for when you need extra torque.

Answer (score 5):

Use a pair of pliers to grab the screwdriver, and while applying downward force to the screwdriver (so it doesn't slip and strip your screws), carefully apply pressure using the pliers.

Comment: I was thinking on the same idea but if you are working with laptop, avoid this method as it can easily scratch the laptop surface. The above pair does a very nice job.

Comment: I agree. It's better to have the right tools (bigger handles), but in a pinch pilers will work. You do absolutely have to be careful though, as you do no matter what tools you're using to work on anything you don't want to break.